# Looping through a dict and inserting values into MySQL database seems to take an unnecessary amount of time

Tags: mysql-python

i'm trying to make a python script that downloads IMDB's top movies and breaks it down into a SQL database. I built it entirely on SQLite3, but due to some problems with SQLite foreign key limitations, i am trying to change it to use MySQL. With SQLite, things used to work alright, and now it takes too much time to return me the tabulate. I've "narrowed" the problem down to the loop, but now i'm stuck in not knowing what could be improved to stop taking so long.

```
curr.execute('''
CREATE TABLE movie_list
(movie_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, movie_rank INT, director_id INT, movie_name VARCHAR(55), year INT)
''')
curr.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS directors
(director_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, director VARCHAR(50))
''')
for key, value in html_parsing.movies_list.items():
    curr.execute('''
    INSERT INTO movie_list(movie_rank, movie_name, year) 
    VALUES(%s, %s, %s)
    ''',(key, value[0], value[2]))
    curr.execute('''
    INSERT INTO directors(director)
    VALUES(%s)
    ''',(value[1],))
    curr.execute('''INSERT INTO movie_list(director_id) SELECT director_id FROM directors ''')
    curr.execute('''ALTER TABLE movie_list 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (director_id) REFERENCES directors(director_id)
    ''')
curr.execute('''
            SELECT
            *
            FROM movie_list LEFT JOIN directors ON movie_list.director_id = directors.director_id''')
df = pd.DataFrame(curr.fetchall())
print(tabulate(df, headers= 'keys', tablefmt= 'psql'))
```

What can be done to improve it?

Comment: running a query in a for loop is a bad idea. You should create an `insert` statement for all the values (a bulk insert) and execute a single query. Also, you are adding a foreign key in the loop which is wrong.

Comment: Looping really was the problem. Also, when taking a closer look at the loop, i saw the dumbness in adding the foreign key there. Managed to fix it with executemany. Thank you so much!